# Make VLC default video player in 17.10

Tags: video, vlc, totem

There is apparently a known bug with the Totem player under Wayland [Totem player not working in Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980080/totem-player-not-working-in-wayland) and so I would like to make VLC the default video player until the bug is fixed.

Previously one could select the default player my right-clicking on a file, selecting a player and then selecting the "Set as default" option but in 17.10 the "Set as default" option is not available.

So, how do I make the VLC player the default video player?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Settings go to Details:

[image]

and then Default Application > Video > VLC

[image]

Comment: Thanks for yor answer, but I've another problem and not sure to post as another question. The problem is I can't find vlc in player list at all even after reinstall and reconfiguring it.